# Dropbox use of "ListFolderAsync" with a filter

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I would like to list the directories at the root of my Dropbox application.
To do that I use the ListFolderAsync function of the Dropbox API and it works.

**`var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync ("");`**

Is it possible to add a filter to this function to retrieve only directories belonging to the filter?
Something like all directories whose names begin with "ABCD"

Thank you for your answers.
YC

Comment: Excuse I forgot to post in English
Hello,
I would like to list the directories at the root of my Dropbox application.
To do that I use the ListFolderAsync function of the Dropbox API and it works.

var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync ("");

Is it possible to add a filter to this function to retrieve only directories belonging to the filter?
Something like all directories whose names begin with "ABCD"

Thank you for your answers.
YC

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm#!) method at the *dropbox* side the folder methods are fairly restrictive, however you can filter them after the fact with *Linq*

Another would be to use, either

- [SearchAsync Method (SearchArg)](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_SearchAsync.htm)
- [FilesUserRoutes.SearchAsync Method (String, String, UInt64, UInt64, SearchMode](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_SearchAsync_1.htm))

> Searches for files and folders.

Though this may not be optimal as you will get files as well.